# Javascript/jQuery attr.replace() issue on Samsung Galaxy S4 built-in browser, looking for work-around

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, responsive-design

One of my websites uses the following HTML code:

```
<img src="imagesHiRes/theImage.jpg">
```

followed by the following Javascript code (using jQuery):

```
path = 'imagesHiRes';

// Low resolution (smartphones):
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 599px)').matches)
  path = 'imagesLowRes';

// Medium resolution (tablets):
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px)').matches)
  path = 'imagesMidRes';

$('img').attr('src', function (index,attr) {
  return attr.replace('imagesHiRes', path);   // Modify image paths
});
```

The idea is to let low-resolution and medium-resolution clients load and display an appropriately sized image which can be art-directed to enhance the experience on small-screen devices (i.e. the image can be modified by an editor to give the optimum experience on a certain platform).

This works fine, except on the Samsung Galaxy S4 using the built-in web browser, in which the image path is translated to **imagesLowResHiRes**.

Apparently the jQuery attr.replace() call works differently (and not according to spec) on the S4's built-in browser.

Is this a known bug of the Android version on the S4 (4.2.2. if memory serves) and is there a work-around available?

Alternatively, is the above (using jQuery to modify image paths post-load) a bad idea and are there better practices? (I've had look at HTML5's `<picture>` element but found it insufficiently supported at this time to use it.)

Update: Live website [here](http://www.brewforafrica.co.za), fiddle (which does not seem to support images as far as I can see) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxfoc17b/).

The jQuery version I'm using is 1.12.1, because I'm in South Africa where IE8 on XP is still relatively widely used.

Comment: [Javascript's "replace" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), not JQuery's.

Comment: I think you might suspecting `replace` a little too soon. Please add some console logging before and after the replace operation to verify the claim that it is actually the`replace` operation that is to blame. Also, please add a fiddle so we can witness the issue first hand, any decent Android developer has an S4 at hand to test on anyway :-)

Comment: Good point. Post edited accordingly. And I'm not a hard-core pro, just a self-taught guy trying to scrape a living together. So I'd love to have one of every model smartphone on the market for testing, but no such luck.  :-)

Not sure how to grab console output from an S4...